# Android Studio, return type required on async task call when not in an activity

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a class Game which should call an async task that downloads some song info.
The async task should not return anything, it just downloads and parses the song so I have no idea why it expects a return...

```
public class Game {
    private Context context;

    public Game(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    String stringUrl = "some link";
    // The error is in the following line asking for a return type
    // If I add this line in an activity it works
    new DownloadSong(context).execute(stringUrl);
}
```

The DownloadSong task looks like this

```
public class DownloadSong extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Song> {

    private Context context;

    public DownloadSong(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

        @Override
    protected Song doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Song fail = null;
        try {
            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "IOException at loadingXmlFromNetwork");
            return fail;   // TO DO handle exception
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "XMLPullParserException at loadingXml");
            return fail;   // TO DO handle exception
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

Why am I getting "Invalid method declaration; return type expected" when calling the task? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers.
Turns out the following helps

```
public class Game extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        downloadSong();
    }

    public void downloadSong(){
        String stringUrl = "some link";
        new DownloadSong(this).execute(stringUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a method

**[UPDATE]**

```
public void DownloadSong(String stringUrl){
    new DownloadSong(context).execute(stringUrl);
}
```

Comment: DownloadSong is not expected to return anything. It is not returning a song, it just downloads it